# ClassCastException in ant schemagen task using jaxb-ri-2.2.7

Tags: java, xml, ant, jaxb, schemagen

I'm trying to use the schemagen ant task from JAXB-RI 2.2.7, but I keep getting "BUILD FAILED .... Error starting ap" on the schemagen task in build.xml.  The relevant stanzas are as follows:

```
<taskdef name="schemagen" classname="com.sun.tools.jxc.SchemaGenTask">
  <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="schemas" description="Compile all Java source files">
 <mkdir dir="${schemas.dir}" />
 <schemagen destdir="${schemas.dir}">
  <src path="${src.dir}"/>
  <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
 </schemagen>
</target>
```

With -verbose, I get the stack trace below.  I've tried googling for the details of the ClassCastException but not found anything.  Any suggestions?

Thanks, Adam

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/adam/sandboxes/adam/sensei/code/trunk/repository/build.xml:99: Error starting ap
    at com.sun.tools.jxc.ApBasedTask$InternalApAdapter.execute(ApBasedTask.java:131)
    at com.sun.tools.jxc.ApBasedTask.compile(ApBasedTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:930)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees cannot be cast to com.sun.source.util.Trees
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:469)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:132)
    at com.sun.tools.jxc.ApBasedTask$InternalApAdapter.execute(ApBasedTask.java:127)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees cannot be cast to com.sun.source.util.Trees
    at com.sun.source.util.Trees.getJavacTrees(Trees.java:84)
    at com.sun.source.util.Trees.instance(Trees.java:73)
    at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.ApNavigator.getClassLocation(ApNavigator.java:410)
    at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.ApNavigator.getClassLocation(ApNavigator.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getLocation(ClassInfoImpl.java:1284)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationException.convert(IllegalAnnotationException.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationException.build(IllegalAnnotationException.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationException.<init>(IllegalAnnotationException.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.createClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:399)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:257)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:390)
    at com.sun.tools.jxc.api.impl.j2s.JavaCompilerImpl.bind(JavaCompilerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.tools.jxc.ap.SchemaGenerator.process(SchemaGenerator.java:110)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees cannot be cast to com.sun.source.util.Trees
    at com.sun.source.util.Trees.getJavacTrees(Trees.java:82)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Did you find a solution? --Thank you , Mark

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. From the stack trace I would say it's some error in JAXB annotation, but while xjc tries to handle that exception it fails with another one and there's no way of knowing in which class and property the problem is.