# When will an object fail to cast to its parent class in Java?

Tags: java, casting, javac, tools.jar

I'm having the same issue as [ClassCastException in ant schemagen task using jaxb-ri-2.2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631851/classcastexception-in-ant-schemagen-task-using-jaxb-ri-2-2-7). However, my biggest question is not about the issue itself, but the exception in the error log:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees cannot be cast to com.sun.source.util.Trees
```

By looking into the problem, I found that `JavacTrees` is a child class of `DocTrees`, and `DocTrees` is a child class of `Trees`. Specifically, the class definitions are:

```java
public class JavacTrees extends DocTrees {
    // ...
}

public abstract class DocTrees extends Trees {
    // ...
}

public abstract class Trees {
    // ...
}
```

The above `ClassCastException` basically means that an object failed to cast into its parent class. I don't remember anything like that in any textbook I read.

Can somebody explain this exception to me? Thanks.

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: This sounds like a classloader problem. If those 2 classes where loaded by different classloaders casting will not work between them. This question seems to be about a similar problem (and a possible solution): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110407/issue-with-the-classloader-of-processingenvironment-from-maven

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS "If those 2 classes where loaded by different classloaders casting will not work between them." Sorry, I'm not familiar with class loaders. May I ask if there's a pointer for me to see this statement? Thank you.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I've made a quick demo to test this behavior: https://github.com/johnlinp/misc-demo/blob/master/two-class-loaders-load-same-class/. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @OHGODSPIDERS for the hint about `ClassLoader`s. I checked the class loaders of `JavacTrees` and `Trees` using a debugger, and here's the results:

- `com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees` was loaded by [`java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/net/FactoryURLClassLoader.html)
- `com.sun.source.util.Trees` was loaded by [`org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm`](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-classworlds/apidocs/org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/realm/ClassRealm.html)

Therefore, the 2 classes are loaded by different `ClassLoader`s. Hence it will fail to cast from `JavacTrees` to `Trees`, even though `Trees` is the parent class of `JavacTrees`.